# Maximum length of an SQL Query

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM feeds f, 
     user_feeds uf 
WHERE (f.id=uf.feed_id and uf.user_id in (1,2,5,6,23,45)) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

This is a query used to construct a user's feeds. The issue I have with this query is that the "uf.user_id in ()" increases as the number of users the user follows increases.

What is the allowed max length of an SQL query? Is there a better way to implement the above query?

Note: I am using ActiveRecord and Postgres.

Comment: I think you need to explain what are "feeds", "user_feeds", and who is "he". Is there any other table of interest? Are the user ids 1, 2, 5, etc. stored in a table?

Comment: feeds: id, feed_type
user_feeds: id, feed_id, user_id

users: id, username

feed_type = [like|comment|etc]
essentially, when someone likes something(say a photo) an entry is made in the "feeds" table, and entries are made into the user_feeds table of the users included in the photo.

Yes 1,2,5 ... are the user ids

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The maximum length of a query that PostgreSQL can process is 2147483648 characters (signed 4-byte integer; see `src/include/lib/stringinfo.h`).

Comment: 2147483648 characters is 2GiB.

Comment: @Peter Eisentraut: The maximum value of int32 is 2147483647, because since C-Strings have a terminating 0-byte, it's intMaxValue (+1?) minus one. Either way, it's < 2147483648. Also, it's now defined in [stringinfo.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/common/stringinfo.c), and the value is #define MaxAllocSize   ((Size) 0x3fffffff) /* 1 gigabyte - 1 */ Which means one gigabyte minus one. How did you get 2 GB ? Has this value been changed in the past since 2011 ?

Comment: @Quolonel Questions: And an off-by-(at-least)-one error. int32.MaxValue is 2147483647 btw.

Answer (score 8):

While there is no (real) limit on the length of the query string, there is a limit on the number of IN (x,y,z...) clauses: 10000, configurable in the postgres.ini-file:

See:
http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/061mc7pxg6/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-in-a-b-c-d-list-in-postgresql :

"In 7.4 and earlier it depends on the max_expr_depth setting."
...
"In 8.0 and later max_expr_depth is gone and the limit depends on
max_stack_depth."

Comment: That's not the "number of IN (x,y,z...) clauses", it's the *length* of *per* clause.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the query size, you could replace the IN (1, 2) with IN (select followed_id from following where follower_id = ?) or whatever the appropriate query would be to find the ids of the followed users from the follower's id.

Comment: Ah, that is a easier way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a subquery to construct the IN portion of your original WHERE clause.  So the result would look something like this:

"SELECT f.* FROM feeds f, user_feeds uf WHERE (f.id=uf.feed_id and uf.user_id in (SELECT followed where follower = id)) ORDER BY created_at DESC"

Obviously the subquery isn't right as I posted it, but that should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-query.  If you have a table that holds the users a member follows your query text won't grow.

For example:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM feeds f, 
     user_feeds uf 
WHERE f.id=uf.feed_id 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
              FROM follows
              WHERE follows.user_id = uf.user_id) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```