# Maximum number of WHERE clauses in SELECT statement in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I had expected this question to be an easy google search but I could not find anything.

What is the maximum number WHERE clauses I can put in a SELECT statement? And are there any performance implications for doing so?

In terms of numbers, the number of WHERE clauses could be 1000+.
Something like this:

```sql
SELECT * from stars
WHERE
   (age > 0 AND age < 5) OR
   (age > 20 AND age < 30) OR
   (age > 50 AND age < 100) OR
   ...
```

In terms of optimizations, the attribute that the WHERE clause will be acting on will be indexed.

EDIT:
Apologies I changed the SQL statement to make sense, instead of always being false

Comment: Not sure about `WHERE`, but the entire query is limited to 2GB https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937695/492773 or 1GB based on another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937695/492773

Comment: There are no limitations on the number of clauses as long as the whole expression evaluates to a boolean. As for the performance impact, try the EXPLAIN keyword to see how postgres will perform your query. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/using-explain.html

Comment: Thanks @lurker, I fixed the SQL statement so that it actually makes sense

Comment: There's performance implications for doing anything in your database. If your WHERE clause is really going to be big enough that you need to worry about this, then I would really rethink your design.